# Microsoft.Practices.Unity assembly error in designer

Tags: c#, unity-container, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to open an ActiveReport file with Windows Forms Designer, but I'm getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.0.414.0, ... ' or one of its dependencies. The specified file could not be found.
```

I checked the callstack and went to the file causing the exception. `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` and `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension` are both included, reference paths are good, dll are in the folder...

Why does the designer throws this exception while compiler doesn't ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what is causing this error, but removing then re-adding references seems to be a partial solution till the error shows again...